# undefined reference when using dllexport

Tags: c++, mingw

I have created a little test program to understand the *`__declspec(dllimport)`* and
*`__declspec(dllexport)`* preproc.

In my solution I have :

1) File: produit.h

```
#pragma once

int  facteur = 5;
int __declspec(dllexport) base = 100;
int __declspec(dllexport) produit(int, int);
```

2) File : produit.cpp

```
#include "produit.h"

int produit(int a, int b)
{
   return facteur * (a*b);
}
```

3) File: produitEx.h

```
#pragma once

__declspec(dllimport) int base;
__declspec(dllimport) int produit(int a, int b);
```

4) File : main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "produitEx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a =5, b=2, c;
    c = base + produit(a, b);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

looks pretty clear and nothing special just exporting fucntions and importing them.

When Compiling (with MinGW) I got those 2 errors :

> ..../main.cpp:8   undefined reference to `_imp___Z7produitii'
>
> ..../main.cpp:8   undefined reference to `_imp__base'

So I did not know what's confusing for the linker ? How to resolve it?

Thank you. (I use MinGW and NetBeans Cpp)

***Just to add: the Same code Works on Visual Studio.***

Comment: Do you link with the *export library*? When creating the DLL there should also be an *export library* created (a `.lib` file) that you need to link with.

Comment: I did not do any link with an export library. in fact I don't see any exported library. Excuse but I don't figure out why should I do such link. Does dllexport means that a DLL will be created !?

Comment: `dllexport` does not mean that dll will be created. You need to build dll yourself, and then link it yourself into your executable.

Comment: where is body function from profuitEx.h? You don't use produit.h

Comment: @VTT but I did not mean to build a dll . all the files are in the same project. Unless you tell me that I can't export than import the same functions and data in the same project.

Comment: @21koizyd : in the produitEx.h I use the imported functions so the body is already known in produit.cpp file

Comment: you need to build dll in spearate project then import it into original

Comment: @Sly_TheKing : so as an answer to my question : if I could export functions then import them on the same project, we will say NO we could'nt do that !!

Comment: If you want to export and then import the same function and data in the same project then you don't need to use function marked with `dllimport` in your application. `dllimport` basically tells that "these functions aren't here". So just include `produit.h`.

Comment: @VTTYeah i am totally ok with you in the second part (including headers) but I am reading a book with the given files and Had the errors and as the dellexport and dllimport are new for me I said I may missed sthing. 

So I ll take ur comment as a correct answer. But one another, why the same code works on Visual Studio ?

Comment: what's the point of building dll for a few functions that you would use only in that project, dlls are meant to be ported between projects

Comment: @VTT The code above was just a test code to understand the dllexport and dllimport. I thought that it makes me able to export things that i can import bypassing the generation of dll/lib themselves (coz I just have to understand better how this works) 

as I know now that those mean that I have to build a sperate dll ... I could tell you that this code means nothing. But Visual is intelligent and build me a lib :D

Comment: Visual Studio has a concept of `import libs`. If you export something then it will produce an `import lib`. Also `__declspec(dllimport)` in VS is a Microsoft-specific extension and it may not always behave the same as gcc extension with the same name. Typically when using gcc you should use `__attribute__ (visibility)` instead.

Comment: So you are not creating a DLL from `produit.cpp`? Then what you're looking for is *not* `dllimport` and `dllexport`. The `dll` prefix of those should be an indicator that those are for when you're creating a DLL. Instead in `produit.h` you should use the `extern` keyword to *declare* the symbols, then *define* then in the source file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is completely fine to use `dllexport` (though somewhat unusual) to export symbols from executable. For example nodejs exports tons of symbols and native plugins need to link to nodejs executable.

Comment: @VTT Yes `dllexport` is okay, when exporting symbols from an executable or DLL. But it's not the same as `extern` which the OP seems to be wanting.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: Thanks for the link, it contains plenty of code and explantion. Good hint.